# Modifying an element in a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

I have generated a list of 100 matrices for a structured population model. I would like to modify element (1,3) of each matrix in the list by multiplying them by a sequence of 100 numbers from 0.01 to 1. The goal is to have row 1, column 3 of the first matrix multiplied by 0.01, the same element in the second matrix by 0.02, and so on.

Thanks

```
Ls<-6.521
Pg<-.318
Sr<-0.5
Sn<-.432
Sj<-.564
Sa<-.501


AA<-lapply(1:100, 
          function(x) { 
                       matrix(c(0, 0, Sr * rnorm(1,Ls,.3886) * rnorm(1,Pg,.1466), 
                                rnorm(1,Sn,.0954),0,0, 0,rnorm(1,Sj,.0468), 
                                rnorm(1,Sa,.472)), 
                             nrow=3, ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))
```

Comment: I have tried modifying the above code to include the sequence within the element [1,3] like so: Sr*rnorm(1,Ls,.3886)*rnorm(1,Pg,.1466) * seq(0.01,1,0.01), but this just results in the element being multiplied by 0.01 in every matrix within the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a `for` loop, easy and clear:

```
for(i in seq_along(AA)) {
  AA[[i]][1, 3] = AA[[i]][1, 3] * i / length(AA)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `map2` function from the `purrr` package.
I defined lists with only two matrices and two scalars but should work for you too.

```
m <- list(m1 = matrix(1, 2, 3),
         m2 = matrix(2, 2, 3))
a <- list(a1 = 0.01, a2 = 0.02)

fun <- function(mymatrix, myx){
  mymatrix[1, 3] <- mymatrix[1, 3]* myx
  return(mymatrix)
} 

purrr::map2(m, a, fun)

$m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1 0.01
[2,]    1    1 1.00

$m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2 0.04
[2,]    2    2 2.00
```